# Use multiple domain names for a single website (advantages & disadvantages)

Tags: performance, search, seo

I've seen some websites uses multiple domain names that pointing to the same website, for example: facebook.com & fb.com, is it bad for SEO or search results or performance, or other?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not a bad SEO to have multiple domain names pointing to the same website.  Many organization use multiple domain names to point to the same website or forward to the same website just to protect their brand name.

But as far as SEO concerned, you have to optimize only one domain name.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple domains, you need to use canonical links, otherwise, you may suffer from a penalty. You way also use 301 permanent redirects instead.

Comment: Why the -1? What is the issue with this answer?